# Alpine linux keep re-installing openssl

Tags: alpine-linux

My `/etc/apk/world` contains

```
alpine-base
busybox-mdev-openrc
chrony
openresolv
openssl
tailscale
```

And when I do

```
# apk info -r openssl
openssl-3.1.1-r1 is required by:

#
```

And `apk del openssl` works. If I then `lbu commit` and `reboot`, I see

```
# lbu diff
Common subdirectories: a/etc/apk/cache and b/etc/apk/cache
--- a/etc/apk/world
+++ b/etc/apk/world
@@ -2,4 +2,5 @@
 busybox-mdev-openrc
 chrony
 openresolv
+openssl
 tailscale
Common subdirectories: a/var/lib/tailscale and b/var/lib/tailscale
#
```

Why is it coming back like that?